# Sending Logging Message with Interceptor in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-integration

Is it possible to configure an interceptor in Spring Integration to specify a logging message?

This is in contrast to using a wire-tap to send the message to a logging channel to which a logging channel adapter subscribes. The problem with this approach is that the logging channel has the expression for what exactly to log. In my use case I'd like to use a global channel-interceptor to specify a logging message and send it to a logging channel adapter, rather than having to define a logging channel adapter for every possible logging message I might want.

For a moment I thought I could define a service activator with an SpEL expression to produce the string logging message (and with an output-channel of the deisred logging channel) inside a channel-interceptor definition, but it's looking for an input-channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a wire-tap, you could make the channels you are interested in `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`s.

Subscribe the appropriate transformer to the channel (with an `output-channel` going to the logging adapter).

You can control whether the log happens before or after the real subscriber using the `order` attribute on the transformer and other subscriber.

Another alternative is a global interceptor that adds a header to the message

```
MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader('foo', routeForThisMessageType).build()
```

Then send it to a `<header-value-router/>` which, in turn, routes to the appropriate transformer, and thence to the single logging channel adapter.

Of course, if you want, you can combine the routing and/or transforming right into the interceptor.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Sadly I can't change the original channels (I've got an 'abstract' project and set of config, and implementing subprojects fill in the gaps). I was hoping to 'decorate' the existing channels with a global interceptor.

Comment: I have added other alternatives to my answer.